# AWS Lambda, .Net Core, & MySql: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I am building out lambda microservices that access data via MySql in RDS. My local unit tests work fine but when I publish to AWS, I get the following error:

```
    {
  "TypeName": "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTrace",
  "Message": "The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTrace' threw an exception.",
  "Data": {},
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.\n",
    "FileName": "System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
    "Data": {},
    "InnerException": {
      "Message": "'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' not found in the deployment package or in the installed Microsoft.NETCore.App.",
      "FileName": null,
      "Data": {},
      "InnerException": null,
      "StackTrace": "   at AWSLambda.Internal.Bootstrap.LambdaAssemblyLoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)\n   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName)\n   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Resolve(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)",
      "HelpLink": null,
      "Source": "Bootstrap",
      "HResult": -2147024894
    },
    "StackTrace": null,
    "HelpLink": null,
    "Source": null,
    "HResult": -2147024894
  },
  "StackTrace": "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTrace.LogError(Int32 id, String msg)\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()\n   at HealthStats.Functions.GetLocationTypes(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)",
  "HelpLink": null,
  "Source": "MySql.Data",
  "HResult": -2146233036
}
```

Here is my project.json file. I have tried to add the `System.Diagnostics.TraceSource` library as a standard project dependency (not shown) and as a framework dependency (shown below). My thinking was maybe during publish it was not adding the assembly because I didn't directly use TraceSource in my code. However, neither attempt resolved the issue:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": false
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents": "1.0.1",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Core": "1.0.0",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json": "1.0.1",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Tools": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.1.0-preview1"
    },
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "MySql.Data": "7.0.6-IR31"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Amazon.Lambda.Tools" : "1.1.0-preview1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Diagnostics.TraceSource": "4.0.0"
      },
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer to this? I'm doing the same thing, except I'm using ef core with the sapientguardian nuget package for mysql.

Comment: Just figured out a resolution to a similar problem.  What I had to do was `dotnet publish` and then copy the dlls from the \publish\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.3 subfolder to the publish folder.  Zip the contents of the publish folder (runtimes folder not included) and upload that to lambda.  Let me know if it works for you @xeon and @SnOrfus

Comment: @JonPeterson If you want to post that as an answer, I'd vote it up. It worked for me. I had tried copying the assembly into the publish folder and then using the publish from within visual studio (thinking it'd pick up the copied assembly) which didn't work. So I was on the right track. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

I was seeing a similar problem in the lambda results:

> The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTrace' threw an exception.: TypeInitializationException
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTrace.LogError(Int32 id, String msg)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
>   at AWSLambda2.Function.FunctionHandler(SNSEvent input, ILambdaContext context)
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )
>
> 'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' not found in the deployment package or in the installed Microsoft.NETCore.App.: FileNotFoundException
>   at AWSLambda.Internal.Bootstrap.LambdaAssemblyLoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
>   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName)
>   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Resolve(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)

What worked for me was manually publishing the project using `dotnet publish` and then within that published folder navigating to `.\publish\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.3` and copying the dlls that were published there into `.\publish`.  Once those were in that folder, I zipped up the contents of the publish folder, excluding the runtimes sub-folder, and uploaded that to lambda.

My working theory for why this happens is because `dotnet publish` is publishing as if an intelligent system is using the results, however I *think* the lambda is loading the assembly into another context which doesn't know about looking in sub-folders for dependencies.

Comment: +1 SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql takes a dependency on System.Diagnostics.TraceSource which doesn't end up in the published folder and fails to find it when it runs in lambda. This worked for me. Thanks again Jon

Comment: Thank you for this workaround. Any ideas on a permanent solution? My goal is to build a development process for C# + Lambda + MySQL.

Comment: @xeon you and me both.  Unfortunately for me my AWS VS toolkit doesn't work correctly (troubles with federated users, sigh).  You can try the answers from @dohmoose and @alduar to copy the files as part of the `dotnet publish`.  Note the assumption for those answers is that you are publishing on Windows - I'm sure there is an equivalent way to copy in other platforms though.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to edit the project.json file.
To add a prepublish event

"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "xcopy ./bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0/publish/runtimes/unix/libnetstandard1.3/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll ./bin/Release/" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
This causes the reference to be copied before the AWS Publishing Wizard copies it.

Regards

Aldo Flores

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @alduar but I think it is more appropriate to put it in postpublish, since the dll will not be there on first build. 
And I think it should be copied to the publish directory.
Note, these file paths are for windows.

```
    "scripts": {
       "postpublish": [ "xcopy bin\\Release\\netcoreapp1.0\\publish\\runtimes\\unix\\lib\\netstandard1.3\\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll bin\\Release\\netcoreapp1.0\\publish\\" ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after running the following command.

`dotnet publish src\Lambda.csproj -c Release`

At first I fixed it by copying the files from `runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.3` like Jon Peterson suggested.

I found a solution which seems cleaner though. Now I just run the following.

`dotnet publish src\Lambda.csproj -c Release -r linux`

This will create a publish folder which contains all the correct files.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, in my case helped to remove from .csproj file line

```
<PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
```